# Mostrar datos con caducidad de un mes

Tags: php, html, mysqli

[image: tabla ventas]

```html
<!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Ganancias (Mensual)</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$<?php
                                  include ("conexion.php");  
                                  $c2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT total, sum(total) FROM ventas ");
                                  $count1=mysqli_fetch_array($c2);
                                  echo $count1[1];
                                ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Tengo este pedazo de código donde muestro con código php el ingreso mensual generado en ventas desde mi base de datos, tengo una pequeña complicación al querer que solo me muestre lo de un mes y al empezar otro mes empiece de ceros, como un reiniciador.

Por ejemplo estamos en octubre y que cuando empiece noviembre se reinicie y muestre nuevo ingreso mensual de noviembre, ya no de octubre.

Espero me puedan ayudar con el código necesario.

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar la estructura de la tabla ventas?

Comment: Que tal, edité la pregunta y anexé una captura de pantalla de la tabla ventas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes escribir la consulta así, para que te filtre siempre los registros por el mes / año actual:

```
SELECT total, sum(total) FROM ventas
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Asumiendo que `fecha` es la columna de tu tabla que guarda la fecha por la que quieres filtrar.

#### Código optimizado

El código se puede optimizar evitando traer datos que no vas a usar, la columna `total` que estás trayendo no la usas. Luego, puedes usar un método más específico para obtener los datos. El método que estás usando te trae los datos dos veces, como arreglo asociativo y como arreglo numérico, por tanto `mysqli_fetch_assoc` es más específico.

Si no vas a usar la columna `total` que pones en el `SELECT`, escribe la consulta así:

```
include ("conexion.php");  
$sql="SELECT sum(total) suma FROM ventas
      WHERE MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
      AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())";
$c2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$count1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($c2);
echo $count1['suma'];
```

#### Otras recomendaciones

Evita nombrar tus variables como `$variable1`, `$talCosa2`. Cuando el programa crezca, ni tú mismo sabrás reconocer qué significa `$variable1` o `$talCosa2`, creando un código imposible de analizar o de comprender por otros. Conviene siempre dar nombres descriptivos a ciertas variables, tales como `$stmt`, `$rs`, `$data`, etc. Son nombres universales, cualquiera que los vea sabrá que estamos ante un *statment*, o un *conjunto de resultados*, o unos *datos* cualesquiera. Pero si ves un `$c2` un `$count1`, ¿?.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos y la ayuda, de verdad me ayudaron mucho.